# Why people still look for short-sellng stocks instead of short selling CFDs

Tags: stocks, trading, stock-markets, international-trading, cfd

I have been doing some research about equity trading and the stock market in general, and I have a doubt. I see that a lot of people is looking for short-selling stocks, but that is not so easy because most brokers wont allow it, I guess this is mainly because sometimes borrowing the shares to do so may not be easy.

But on my research, I also found that is it possible to short sell a CFD of a stock, and a lot of brokers allow this on all their instruments. *(Always talking about non US citizens since I think they are not allowed to trade CFD)*

**So why would people still look for short selling a stock (with borrowed shares), instead of just using CFDs? What are the pros/cons (besides margin on cfds) of one over the other?**

Answer (score 2):

Investopedia has a nice article on this [here](http://www.investopedia.com/articles/stocks/09/trade-a-cfd.asp)

The Key benefit looks like better returns with lower capital.

The disadvantage is few brokers offering that can be trusted. Potentially lower return due to margins / spreads. Higher leverage and can become an issue.

Comment: I understand that margin is a clear difference between short-selling stocks and short-selling CFDs, but as I said on the question, besides that, why people still look for short-selling stocks (which seems to be hard) when they can short-sell CFDs (which seems to be easier)?, I think margin can be kind of irrelevant because you can risk the same amount with or without margin (if you have enough cash).